# Guid and int identity columns, with code first migrations in MVC, SQL Server, ordering

Tags: c#, sql, database, migration, identity

I have pretty interesting question, I have a database where my primary key is Guid. After some months of using it, some guys asked me to add Number column, so the records in table will be numbered. What I did, I just added entity framework code first migration with new column and decorated it with data annotation for identity

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Number;
```

Because of primary key type guid, my records in the table are not in order from top to bottom, they randomly appear between old records. After I use my migration, numbers are also messed up.

So the main question: is it possible to force autoincrement to add numbers by the order of record created time? 
P.S my entity has property CreatedTime, so I was ordering records by this column, but the numbers new column Numbers appears to be random

```
Number |  CreatedTime 
 107   |   today 13:30
  1    |   today  13:00
      ....
  200  |  today 11:00
```

the table shows "ORDER BY CreatedTime DESC". Any ideas how to fix numbers? Maybe any SQL scripts that updates identity column?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: woops. it's SQL

Comment: That is not a database.  SQL Server, for instance, is a database.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was trying to understand this problem, so now I got it working where I needed. Locally I am using SQL Server, but in the Server there is SQL Express, so express saves records as I expected from top to bottom, so there were no problems to deal with, when SQL Server saves records in different order when key is of type uniqueidentifier (Guid). Sorry for my bad english and slow answer, but the answer is no longer needed for question. And yea, I started to think about updating and turning off identity column etc. I'm glad I didn't have to. Thanks :)